# Private Beta reference in Help > Asking

Tags: bug, help-center

The [*Asking section*](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/asking) of the help center still shows the page [*How to Ask Questions in Private Beta*](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask-beta). I think that should be removed as we're not in private beta any more.

[image: Beta question links are displayed in the menu and on the asking page]

Comment: I've closed this here since it's a site-wide issue that's [already been reported on Meta StackExchange.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290401/how-to-ask-questions-in-private-beta-is-listed-in-every-site-s-help-centre)

Comment: Thank you @Lilienthal. I didn't see that.